# Updating two pagination components on click in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two pagination components in one page. One at the Top and the other at the bottom, so that users can use the paginate without having to scroll down below.

The problem is when I click on page 2 from the top component, the pagination works perfectly but the bottom component still displays current page as 1. Same thing happens for the bottom component as well. The changes does not take place in both the component at the same time.

What I am trying to achieve is when I select page 2 from the top component the bottom component should also mark the current page as page 2 and vice versa.

Could you please tell me how to fix this?

My code looks like following. You can see it live here: https://jsfiddle.net/c9wp2k63/107/

The pagination component that I am using is : https://github.com/matfish2/vue-pagination-2

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Vue Pagination 2</h2>
  <p>Selected page: {{page}}</p>
  <h3>Top Pagination</h3>
  <pagination :records="10000" :per-page="100" @paginate="setPage">
 </pagination>

 <h3>Bottom Pagination</h3>
 <pagination :records="10000" :per-page="100" @paginate="setPage">
 </pagination>
</div>



    new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: {
        Pagination
    },
    data: {
        page: 1
    },
    methods: {
        setPage: function(page) {
            this.page = page;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The solutions given below seems use the refs. They do the job, but a better way is to use the stores, in that way your solution will scale, otherwise you will end up with multiple if's and else's.
Go through the https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch for understanding the states with stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inspecting the lib's code ([[1]](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-pagination-2/blob/master/src/template.js#L15), [[2]](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-pagination-2/blob/master/src/Pagination.js#L134)), the only way I see is using `refs` to get a handle of the components, and then calling [`Pagination.setPage(page)`](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-pagination-2/blob/master/src/Pagination.js#L134) on them.

The caveat is the [`Pagination.setPage(page)`](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-pagination-2/blob/master/src/Pagination.js#L134) triggers the [paginate event](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-pagination-2/blob/master/src/Pagination.js#L146) again, so you have to add an `if` to prevent a stack overflow error.

[Here's your **JSFiddle, updated**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/c9wp2k63/146/).

#### Breakdown:

Add `ref="topPagination"` and `ref="bottomPagination"` to the template:

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Vue Pagination 2</h2>
  <p>Selected page: {{page}}</p>
  <h3>
  Top Pagination
  </h3>
  <pagination :records="10000" :per-page="100" @paginate="setPage" ref="topPagination">
  </pagination>

  <h3>
  Bottom Pagination
  </h3>
   <pagination :records="10000" :per-page="100" @paginate="setPage" ref="bottomPagination">
  </pagination>
</div>
```

Add `if` and `$refs...setPage()`:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    Pagination
  },
  data: {
    page: 1
  },
  methods: {
    setPage: function(page) {
      if (page === this.page) { /* prevent stack overflow */ return; }
      this.page = page;
      this.$refs.bottomPagination.setPage(page);
      this.$refs.topPagination.setPage(page);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This looks fantastic! Thank you very much for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I got it working :)
https://jsfiddle.net/c9wp2k63/144/

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    Pagination
  },
  data: {
    page: 1,
  },
  methods: {
    setPageFirst: function(page) {
        const IsNewPage =  this.page != page
      this.page = page;

      if ( IsNewPage ){
                this.$refs.secondPagination.setPage(page)
      }
    },
    setPageSecond: function(page) {
        const IsNewPage =  this.page != page

      this.page = page;
      if ( IsNewPage ){
         this.$refs.firstPagination.setPage(page)
       }
    }
  }
});
```